# What is LINQ in following code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

```
 // GET: racunTest/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        racun racun = db.racuns.Find(id);
        if (racun == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.kupac_id = new SelectList(db.kupacs, "id_kupac", "naziv", racun.kupac_id);
        return View(racun);
    }

    // POST: racunTest/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id_racun,dv_racuna,status,dv_placanja,kupac_id")] racun racun)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(racun).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.kupac_id = new SelectList(db.kupacs, "id_kupac", "naziv", racun.kupac_id);
        return View(racun);
    }

    // GET: racunTest/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        racun racun = db.racuns.Find(id);
        if (racun == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(racun);
    }

    // POST: racunTest/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        racun racun = db.racuns.Find(id);
        db.racuns.Remove(racun);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Is here any LINQ in this code?And what is it, or is it all LINQ. I have to get simple data from DB using LINQ, but it looks f**king hard, i dont even know where I should, put that LINQ code, and how to display data? Is LINQ nad LINQ to SQL same thing?

Comment: Try looking at [LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) & [Language Integrated Query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). A simple search on Google also would be a good idea. Your question isn't really on-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it does not really offer much value for future readers and a simple Google search would give you all the answers you need.

Comment: Replace `Find` with `FirstOrDefault` and it would be Linq, and be pretty much the same as it is. The difference is that Linq gives **1** a common set of methods that can be used with different collection-like sources of entities (collections, XML documents, database tables) and **2** (in some languages) a query-like syntax that can be used with some of those methods. `FirstOrDefault` is one of those methods (on by `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Jon Hanna, Thx for your help :)

Comment: Research the classes in the `System.Linq` namespace, but note that "linq" is also used of classes in other libraries that are designed work closely with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question show complete lack of effort to investigate the matter.

LINQ = Language INtegrated Queries; It's language construct that allows you to query objects / databases / other in a manner similar to SQL.

Start by reading some guide like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)

Comment: I have been reading about LINQ at least 3 hours, looking some exampls, try to do some, but simply i dont get it. And guess what, i'm preaty good with SQL :/. This LINQ is looking so unfriendly and useless. Can u just tell me, is this... "racun racun = db.racuns.Find(id);
        db.racuns.Remove(racun);
        db.SaveChanges();" LINQ code, and is all i need to write my own LINQ code new action inside this controller? Thx for your time. :)

Comment: There's no single LINQ statement in your code.

LINQ to SQL is one of examples of LINQ, which is probably the one you want if you want to deal with database.

Comment: You technically can, but it's not good design. Usually you want to have some data access classes / services that you would call from controller.

Comment: Hm...in MVC form, in which folders are saved that classes? Looks LINQ is even harder then i though, a lot of job is in front of me.I rly appreciate your help, thx dude, a lot.